# Closing a switch/do loop C++

Tags: c++

I just wanted to find out how I would go about closing this loop. Every time I try to compile this code it has an error that it is "expecting a while"
In my case I was wondering what the "while would be"

```
do
{
    write("Choose wisely: ");

    line = read_line();
    option - convert_to_integer(line);

    switch(option)
    {   
        case 1:

            test_details();
            break;
        case 2:

            guessing_game();
            break;
        case 3:

            write_line("Goodbye and Good Riddance");
            break;
            write_line("Please enter an option from the menu");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pick one of [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) please. Hot tip of the day: There's no such thing like a _"do / switch loop"_ in c++.

Comment: If you don't know how to use a `do` - `while` construct, why did you write `do {` in your code?   It looks like you're just hacking code without thinking about what it does - and doing that is a terrible way to learn how to program - or to do programming.

Answer (score 1):

c++ has what is called a do-while loop. It looks something like this.

```
do {
    // the code to run in the loop
} while (someCondition)
```

The point of this loop it that it always runs at least once, then depending on the condition it will keep repeating until it is false.

You code has a big `do` block without any `while` after it.

Just remove the `do` block, or add a `while` condition to it.